# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsattributedstring

I am updating my source in Swift 4.0 I am facing below issue related to attributes text

The below code is working fine in swift 3.2.

```
entemessageText.highlightTapAction = { (containerView: UIView, text: NSAttributedString, range: NSRange, rect: CGRect) -> () in
        let attributes = text.attributes(at: range.location, effectiveRange: nil)
        if let attrs = attributes["YYTextHighlight"] as? YYTextHighlight {
            if let url = attrs.userInfo!["url"] as? String {
                self.openUrl(URL(string: url)!)
            }
        }
    }
```

"Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]' with an index of type 'String'"[image]

I have search for solution with same keyword  but did not get any result.

Any help or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: `if let attrs = attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.init("YYTextHighlight")] as? YYTextHighlight` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 4 - NSAttributedString representation is changed.

The types are not `[String: AnyObject]` anymore. Its `[NSAttributedStringKey:Any]`

So your attributes should accessed like this:

```
if let attrs = attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.init("YYTextHighlight")] as? YYTextHighlight
```